# See source code from PhoneGap/Cordova web view

Tags: security, cordova, cordova-2.0.0

I am using PhoneGap/Cordova 2.0 to build IOS and Android apps. I am little worried about code security using Cordova, as all code is in HTML, Javascript and not compiled. 
Is there a way to see the code from app UIWebView? Can someone do view source code from UIWebView. 
If so, then how to obfuscate the code?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

of course we can see the source code, starting iOS 6 there is an option in settings to enable to debug webcontent from a desktop safari.

Furthermore, your app will be distributed as an .ipa file, which is a .zip file, uncompress it and you will get your resources

how you can obfuscate the code? you can't really, you can make the html code harder to read, but you will never prevent from someone copying it.